# How do you hide and show a background image using a carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am really new to j-query.  This might be pretty embarrassing, but I am having a lot of trouble finding out how to create a slider image carousel using a full background image. I have looked at other solutions, however it seems like you have to have a fixed width of the size of all pictures you want to slide (example a div width of 9000px). However, I feel like I could use some type of array or index function where I can iterate something with a loop to hide and show.  The transition from going from basic javascript to jquery is something I am having trouble adjusting. If anyone could give me some advice or tips that would be great.  Here is my code below. Thanks

http://codepen.io/kevk87/pen/PPNPmg

```
    <main>

<div class="container">
<ul>  
  <li class="one"> 
  </li>
  <li class="two"> </li>
  <li class="three"></li>
  <li class="four"></li>
</ul>

  <div class="nav">
      <ul >
       <li class="first active"> </li>
      <li class="second"> </li>
       <li class="third"> </li>
      <li class="fourth"> </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</ul>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



ul {
  list-style:none;
  height:100%;
}
main, html, body{
  height:100%;
}

.container {
  height:100%;
  postion:relative;

}

.one {  
   height:100%;   background:url(http://hamderser.dk/blog/images/clairvoyant/clairvoyant-nature-nature2.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed; 
   background-size:cover;

}  

.two {
  background: url(http://www.atilaminates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature-wlk.jpeg) center center no-repeat fixed;
  height:100%; 
}
.three {
  background: url(http://php.drishinfo.com/photostudioone/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/nature-wallpaper-hd-1920x1080.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed;
  height:100%; 
}
.four {
  background: url(http://www.projecthappyhearts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/green-nature-dual-monitor-other.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed;
  height:100%; 
}


.nav ul li {
  width:20px;
  background-color:white;
  height:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:20px; 
}
.nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right:0px;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:100px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.nav ul .active{
  background-color:black;
}

.two, .three, .four {
  display:none;
}
```

Javascript

```
//change active class

    $('.nav ul').click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('active');  
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

//Click handlers to change image and active class


$('.first').click(function(){
    $('.one').show();
  $('.two').hide();
  $('.three').hide();
  $('.four').hide();
});


$('.second').click(function(){
    $('.two').show();
  $('.one').hide();
  $('.three').hide();
  $('.four').hide();
});

$('.third').click(function(){
    $('.three').show();
  $('.one').hide();
  $('.two').hide();
  $('.four').hide();
});

$('.fourth').click(function(){
    $('.four').show();
  $('.one').hide();
  $('.three').hide();
  $('.two').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Nice and simplified version using jquery functions.

http://jsfiddle.net/7erakxad/

```
  <main>

<div class="container">
<ul>  
  <li class="one"> 
  </li>
  <li class="two"> </li>
  <li class="three"></li>
  <li class="four"></li>
</ul>

  <div class="nav">
      <ul >
       <li class="first active"> </li>
      <li class="second"> </li>
       <li class="third"> </li>
      <li class="fourth"> </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</ul>
</main>


 <script>
  $(".nav > ul li").click(function () {
        $('.nav > ul li').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');       
        });
        var index = $(this).index();
        $(".container > ul").find("li").each(function (i2) {
            if (index == $(this).index())
                $(this).show();
            else
                $(this).hide();
        });
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });



 </script>

   <style>
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



ul {
  list-style:none;
  height:100%;
}
main, html, body{
  height:100%;
}

.container {
  height:100%;
  postion:relative;

}

.one {  
   height:100%;   background:url(http://hamderser.dk/blog/images/clairvoyant/clairvoyant-nature-nature2.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed; 
   background-size:cover;

}  

.two {
  background: url(http://www.atilaminates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature-wlk.jpeg) center center no-repeat fixed;
  height:100%; 
}
.three {
  background: url(http://php.drishinfo.com/photostudioone/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/nature-wallpaper-hd-1920x1080.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed;
  height:100%; 
}
.four {
  background: url(http://www.projecthappyhearts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/green-nature-dual-monitor-other.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed;
  height:100%; 
}


.nav ul li {
  width:20px;
  background-color:white;
  height:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:20px; 
}
.nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right:0px;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:100px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.nav ul .active{
  background-color:black;
}

.two, .three, .four {
  display:none;
}


  </style>
```

Comment: Hey DinoMyte, Thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: I have a question however. As a student, I am trying to understand how the code works. On lines 5-7 on the javascript, is the function finding the user index value of their choice.  Then it is matching the index value of the container index value? Thanks

Comment: Since you have same number of 'li' in both divs, the whole idea was to check the index of the corresponding 'li' ( having the classes for showing the image ) match with the one which is clicked. One thing to understand and remember is the concept of 'this', which refers to the element which invoked the event or the element which an each loop is currently iterating. $(this).index() gives the index of the li. So we can compare which item we want to show and which to hide. I hope that keeps you some basic idea on what was done here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I guess my main problem is trying to switch gears into jquery after learning the basics of javascript.  It feels like I want to somehow do everything in javascript, but jquery just makes it a lot simpler than it should be.  Maybe I am just overthinking it...